# Return daily sales value for the current month in Django

Tags: django, django-models

With the model below, I want to create a **function** that returns the **details of daily sales** for the current month.
The details will be the total number of sales for each day and sum of sales for each day.
I've tried using **ExtractDay** and **annotate** but I'm not getting the desired output or maybe I'm not doing it right

```
class Stamping(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Order(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

In my location, the date is Tuesday, 2 November 2021. So the output should look like this
`<QuerySet [{'day': 1, 'count': 9, 'total': 100.0}, {'day': 2, 'count': 7, 'total': 80.0}]>`
And after today, I should also `{'day': 3, 'count': 15, 'total': 200.0}` and it keeps going till the end of the month then I'll start getting only the data for that month too

Answer (score 0):

Connect the order model with the stamping one

Change stamping created field from DateTimr to DateFirld
Use celery to create a new stamping object at 00:00 of each new day with the created field equals today's date
So when creating the order object just get the stamping object with today's date
And whenever you want just make an api to return the related orders to today's stamping object using the related name specified in the foreign key field connecting order to stamping

Answer (score 0):

bellow code is creating the query set by taking attribute which you want by lookups it will give the separate out put of day ,count and total value after getting that query_set store create or store them as you want

you can add them in one model and can call them by filter from filter

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Q


def get_queryset(self):
            qlookup1 = Q(day=self.request.value)
            qlookup2 = Q(count=self.request.value)
            qlookup3 = Q(total=self.request.value)
            queryset = model.objects.filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2 | qlookup3).distinct()
            active = self.request.query_params.get('active', True)
            try:
                queryset = queryset.filter(is_active=active)
                return queryset
            except Exception as error:
                return queryset.none()
```

if you want flat formate queryset then you can use   [`drf_multiple_model`](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)